# Sorting columns in GridView

Tags: c#, sorting, gridview, devexpress

I use such method to sort columns in GridView

```
private BandedGridView bandedGridView;

public void SetControlsSortOrder(ColumnSortOrder sortOrder)
        {
            bandedGridView.BeginDataUpdate();
            try
            {
                bandedGridView.SortInfo.ClearSorting();
                bandedGridView.SortInfo.Add(new GridColumnSortInfo(colName, sortOrder));
            }
            finally
            {
                bandedGridView.EndDataUpdate();
            }
        }
```

When `sortOrder` is `Ascending` or `Descending` method works fine, but when `sortOrder` is `None` columns in table is sorted by descending.
Could you help me solve this problem?

Comment: did you check your datasource ? maybe data coming already sorted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `colName` is grouped then its sort order cannot be set to `ColumnSortOrder.None` value and your column using the last sort order that was applied to it. If your `colName` is not grouped then check for [sort glyph](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument537) if you see sort glyph then sorting is applied to your column. If you can not see sort glyph then your `DataSource` is coming already sorted as [mentioned by Burak Ogutken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676982/sorting-columns-in-gridview#comment38272469_24676982).
Also, for sorting use `BandedGridView.BeginSort` and `BandedGridView.EndSort` methods. To set the sort order you simply can use the `BandedGridColumn.SortOrder` property. To clear sorting you can use `BandedGridView.ClearSorting` method.
Here is example:

```
public void SetControlsSortOrder(ColumnSortOrder sortOrder)
    bandedGridView.BeginSort();
    try {
       bandedGridView.ClearSorting();
       colName.SortOrder = sortOrder;
    }
    finally {
       bandedGridView.EndSort();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is exist some workaround to apply `ColumnSortOrder.None` for grouped column?

Comment: @Mykhalik No, I think there are no way. But, you can set [`BandedGridColumn.SortMode`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_SortModetopic.aspx) to [`ColumnSortMode.Custom`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraGridColumnSortModeEnumtopic.aspx) value and handle the [`BandedGridView.CustomColumnGroup`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomColumnGrouptopic) event.